# Disable sync center via powershell wmiinstance

Tags: windows, powershell, administration

I haven't idea why this command output errors. Enabled property should work.

`Set-WmiInstance -Class win32_OfflineFilesCache -Property Enabled = "False"`

If i change -Property to -Arguments i can't change value of "Enabled". So in above command i still can't change value.

Any ideas or hints?

Comment: For the record, if you get an error message you really should include it in your question. Anyway, try -Arguments @{Enabled="false:} and see if that does the trick.

Comment: I think you are looking for the [`Enable` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb309184(v=vs.85).aspx). The `Enabled` property is Read-Only.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all i solve it like this:

`Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\CscService" -Name "Start" -Value 1`